# Let $A$ a set and suppose for each $x\in A$ exists a subset $G_x$ of $A$ such that $x\in G_x$. Prove $A=\bigcup_{x\in A}G_x$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ a set and suppose for each $x\in A$ exists a subset $G_x$ of $A$ such that $x\in G_x$. Prove $A=\bigcup_{x\in A}G_x$

**My work:** 
Let $x_1\in A$ then exists a subset $G{_{x_1}}$ of $A$.

Let $x_2\in A$ then exists a subset $G_{x_2}$ of $A$

.

.

.

Then for $x_i\in A$ with $i\in |A|$ we have exists a subset $G_{x_i}\subset A$ with $i\in |A|$ this implies $A=\bigcup_{x\in A}G_x$

I don't sure of my proof. Can someone help me?

Comment: You never use that $x \in G_x$ in your proof.

Comment: Also the cardinality of A and indexing the elements is unnecessary and probably misleading.  The elements are being indexed by A itself.  Also $i \in |A|$ doesn't make any sense.  And you can't assume $x$ is countable or that this is a countable union.

Comment: A standard approach to show two sets (here $A$ and $\cup_{x\in A} G_x$) are equal is to show each is a subset of the other.  So you should look at the claims $A\subseteq \cup_{x\in A} G_x$ and $ \cup_{x\in A} G_x \subseteq A$ and attempt to find which (if any) is easier than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in A$, so $x\in G_{x}$ and $G_{x}\subseteq A$ for some $G_{x}$, so in particular, $x\in G_{x}\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in A}G_{x}$, and hence $x\in\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in A}G_{x}$. This is true for all $x\in A$, and hence $A\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in A}G_{x}$.

For $a\in\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in A}G_{x}$, then $a\in G_{x}$ for some $G_{x}$ such that $G_{x}\subseteq A$, so $a\in A$, this shows $\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in A}G_{x}\subseteq A$.